# Index with sql execution

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my DDL for create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE utenti
(
  login text NOT NULL,
  nome text NOT NULL,
  cognome text NOT NULL,
  password text NOT NULL,
  admin boolean DEFAULT false,
  CONSTRAINT login PRIMARY KEY (login)
);

CREATE TABLE appunti
  (
    nomeappunto text NOT NULL,
    descrizione text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT nomeappunto PRIMARY KEY (nomeappunto)
  );

CREATE TABLE lezioni
  (
    nomelezione text NOT NULL,
    descrizione text NOT NULL,
    nomeappunto text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT nomelezione PRIMARY KEY (nomelezione),
    CONSTRAINT nomeappunto FOREIGN KEY (appunti)
      REFERENCES nomeappunto(appunti) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
  );

CREATE TABLE corsi
  (
    nomecorso text NOT NULL,
    descrizione text NOT NULL,
    nomelezione text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT nomecorso PRIMARY KEY (nomecorso),
    CONSTRAINT nomelezione FOREIGN KEY (nomelezione)
      REFERENCES nomelezione(lezioni) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
  );
```

When I execute this sql file pgadmin returns:

> ```
> ERROR:  "nomeappunto" is an index
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: "nomeappunto" is an index
> SQL state: 42809
> ```

Comment: Please add the error message as text so it will be found by search engines and help others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your reference `nomeappunto`, but that isnt a table

```
CONSTRAINT nomeappunto FOREIGN KEY (appunti)
  REFERENCES nomeappunto(appunti) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

The sintaxis is:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT constrain_name 
    FOREIGN KEY (local_field_name) 
    REFERENCES foreign_table_name (foreign_field_name) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

So you probably want;

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/NWZIL73602)**

```
CREATE TABLE lezioni
(
    nomelezione text NOT NULL,
    descrizione text NOT NULL,
    nomeappunto text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT nomelezione_pk PRIMARY KEY (nomelezione),
    CONSTRAINT nomeappunto_fk FOREIGN KEY (nomeappunto)
      REFERENCES appunti(nomeappunto) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE corsi
(
    nomecorso text NOT NULL,
    descrizione text NOT NULL,
    nomelezione text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT nomecorso_pk PRIMARY KEY (nomecorso),
    CONSTRAINT nomelezione_fk FOREIGN KEY (nomelezione)
      REFERENCES lezioni(nomelezione) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Additional I suggest you create a different name for the constrains, like:

```
CONSTRAINT nomeappunto_pk PRIMARY KEY (nomeappunto)
CONSTRAINT nomeappunto_fk FOREIGN KEY (appunti)
```